# importing npm packages into electron

Tags: javascript, npm, import, electron

I know there are a lot of questions like this but i cannot find a good answer that explains this issue so i know to work around it in the future. Im trying to import codemirror into my electron app and both import statements and the require functions do not work.

```
import { EditorView, basicSetup } from "codemirror"
const { EditorView, basicSetup } = require("codemirror")
```

When I use the import statement I get an error that says

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "codemirror". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".**

And then when I use require I get an error saying

**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

All I would like is an explanation of why this is happening and ways to get around it. Thankyou.

Comment: According to their [docs](https://codemirror.net/docs/ref/) you should use `"@codemirror/..."` when importing.

Comment: This doesn't help either of the issues i showed